# IOException error in Lucene

Tags: java, exception, lucene

Has anyone encountered this issue?

`java.io.IOException: null: NIOFSIndexInput`

It is happening intermittently for me and despite the suggestion that it might be a corrupted index, the index checks out with no problems.

Comment: Where is this happening? Stack traces? Sample code?